# Shared library built on Ubuntu with -ljpeg doesn't work on Debian

Tags: debian, ubuntu, gcc

I am making a shared library using C language. This lib has a dependencies from libjpeg and X api. I am building it on Ubuntu 18.04 OS and to build it I use the following command: `gcc mycode.c -o libname.so --shared -lX11 -lXss -lXExt -ljpeg -fPIC`.

I want to use this library on debian based operating systems, for example Debian OS. When I call functions of this library on Debian 9.9, I receive an exception `Unable to load a file libname.so or one of it's dependencies`. But when I build this C code with the same command on Debian and further use it - all is working.

I assume that the problem is in **libjpeg** because on Ubuntu I use library called **libjpeg** but there is no library with the same name on Debian and I use **libjpeg-turbo**.

Help me please to realize how to build my library in Ubuntu and then use it on other Debian based systems.

Also, I want to mention that I am not an expert at Linux distributions and difference between them, and if things that I want to do are impossible, sorry for time wasting.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the exact error you’re getting, with the real library name, including numbers, instead of `libname.so`?

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
ldd path/to/your/libname.so
```

on the Debian system then `ldd` will show you what it thinks that library links to and whether the ld.so will be able to resolve/find the listed libraries.

That should show you what the actual problem is and which dependency/library you are missing on the Debian system.

Even better would be to do:

```
ldd path/to/the/executable_that_links_to_libname
```

because that would show you (and us here) the information you've omitted above.